How to fix error "KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction" when trying to use Hilt?
I'm trying to implement Hilt into my application. However when I try to launch the app I get an error in the build log that says:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    > A failure occurred while executing 
    org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction

I've made the app as simple as possible to test it out. It's just a text composable centered in a blue column that takes up the entire screen. Here's the code.
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var classSample: ClassSample

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .fillMaxSize(),
            ) {
                Text(text = classSample.displayMessage(), color = Color.Red, fontSize = 30.sp)
            }
        }
    }
}

I've injected the text composable with a function from a class call "ClassSample" It's supposed to display "Hello, World" on screen. Here is the code for the class.
class ClassSample @Inject constructor() {
    fun displayMessage(): String {
        return "Hello, world!"
    }
}

This is my project level gradle file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}

Here is the module level gradle file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.weeklyplanner2"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.weeklyplanner2"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

    // Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.49")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}


There are several issues:

When using Hilt you need an explicit Application class so you can annotate it with @HiltAndroidApp:
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application()


This class then needs to be referenced in your AndroidManifest.xml:
...
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...


You mix different Hilt versions:

com.google.dagger.hilt.android uses 2.44
com.google.dagger:hilt-android uses 2.49
com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler uses 2.44

They must all use the same version. You can use the current version 2.51.1 (at the time of writing).
It would be easiest if you extract the version number to a central location. As you already use a version catalog for the rest of your dependencies I would suggest you migrate the Hilt dependencies as well: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs



If this answered your question you can upvote and accept it (the check mark left to the answer).

Changing version to latest also worked for me.
